# i have been trying to parse a website and when using urllib2.urlopen i have been getting a error

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, urlopen

can anyone explain me to login to this link(ftpservice.acesphere.com) through python

Comment: Bring cookie/authen token with your request; otherwise, your request will be anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access requires NTLM authentication. You can try [python-ntlm](https://github.com/mullender/python-ntlm) package:

```
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
import urllib2

url = "http://ftpservice.acesphere.com/stocks/indices/master/indicesmaster_new.ace"
user = r'domain\user'
password = "password"

pm = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pm.add_password(None, "http://ftpservice.acesphere.com/", user, password)
auth = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(pm)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print response.read()
```

Comment: I have tried entering using my password and user credentials .. but i ended up getting same error

Comment: You could show your actual code with empty or fake credentials.

Comment: the website i am trying to parse is like .ace unlike a normal one which has .html at the end.. Is this the reason for my errors

Comment: No. Have you tried my code? Did you get the same error?

Comment: yeah i got that before u said... that's NTLM authentication...but anyway thanks for your time and ur passion to share your knowledge

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Meta-comment: I'm not sure writing this guy's code for him is very helpful either for him or for future users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

This means that the website is returning an HTTP 401 Unauthorized status code.  Either catch the exception or modify your request to not produce this error.

See also: [`urllib2` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError)

Comment: can u explain me more detailed

Comment: @SandeepreddyBhimireddy What do you want explained?